# How do I update the review list when a new feedback is posted

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to update the review list when I post a new feedback. I tried adding a `useState` and updates its state when ever POST API of feedback is executed. but it was not fruitful since no changes were observed. I still have to navigate back and forth to see the changes. What am I lacking in my code? Someone suggested me to use Pusher and some even suggested it is not possible etc.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Modal,
    TextInput,
    Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import { Button, Paragraph, Wrapper } from '../components';
import { baseStyle, images, theme, routes } from '../config';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext';



export const Reviews = ({ route }) => {
    const { userInfo } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const navigation = useNavigation();


    const [isModalVisible, setisModalVisible] = useState(false);
    const { item } = route.params;
    const [responseData, setResponseData] = React.useState();
    const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(0);

    const handleSubmit = async () => {
        console.log('Submitted Feedback: ', text);
        if (text.trim() === ''){
            Alert.alert('Error', 'Feeback cannot be blank');
        }
        else{
            await axios.post(`https://514c-119-157-87-212.ngrok-free.app/listing/${item.id}/feedback`, {
            feedback: text, token: userInfo.data
        }).then(res => {
            let FeedbackInfo = res.data;
            // setFeedbackinfo(FeedbackInfo);
            // AsyncStorage.setItem('FeedbackInfo', JSON.stringify(FeedbackInfo));
            setRefresh(refresh+1);
            console.log(FeedbackInfo);
            Alert.alert('Success',FeedbackInfo.message);
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(`feedback error ${e}`);

        });
        setisModalVisible(!isModalVisible);
    }
}
        React.useState(async () => {
            await axios.get(`https://514c-119-157-87-212.ngrok-free.app/listing/${item.id}/feedback`)
                .then(response => {
                    setResponseData(response.data.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }, [refresh]);

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <View style={styles.header} >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                    <Image source={images.back} style={styles.backIcon} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                < Text style={styles.headerText} > Reviews </Text>
            </View>
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.review} >
                {console.log(responseData)}
                {responseData &&
                    responseData.length > 0
                    ?
                    responseData.map((item) => (
                        <View style={styles.reviewContainer}>
                            <View style={styles.flex} >
                                <Paragraph style={styles.reviewer} > {item.name} </Paragraph>
                            </View>
                            <Paragraph>
                                {item.feedback_desc}
                            </Paragraph>
                        </View>
                    ))
                    :
                    null
                }
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.footer} >
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Button onPress={() => {
                        if (userInfo.data) setisModalVisible(true);
                        else navigation.navigate(routes.LOGIN, { item: item });
                    }}> Post a review </Button>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <Modal
                transparent={true}
                animationType='slide'
                visible={isModalVisible}
            >
                <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                    label="Review"
                    multiline={true}
                    //Capitalize="none"
                    mode="outlined"
                    activeOutlineColor={theme.colors.blue}
                    style={{ height: 40 }}
                    placeholder="Type here to enter a feedback"
                    onChangeText={newText => setText(newText)}
                    value={text}
                    />
                    <View style={{...styles.modalButtonContainer, width: '70%'}}>
                        <Button onPress={() => handleSubmit()}> Submit </Button>
                        <Button onPress={() => setisModalVisible(false)}> Close </Button>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </Wrapper >
    );
};
```

Comment: you're looking for useEffect, not useState, for your async function

Comment: using useEffect will fix the problem? I often get "Object is not a function" error when POST API is executed.

Comment: will post an answer with more info. re "Object is not a function", would need more info, sounds like a separate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` doesn't work like that - you may be thinking of useEffect.

```js
        // original code
        React.useState(async () => {
            await axios.get(`https://514c-119-157-87-212.ngrok-free.app/listing/${item.id}/feedback`)
                .then(response => {
                    setResponseData(response.data.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }, [refresh]);
```

The above code would store your async function in state, returning an array of the state and the setter.  However the return value of this isn't used, so it would simply run your code once and never affect anything again.

useState doesn't take a second argument (the dependency array) so that won't be used.

Rewriting this with useEffect would look something like:

```js
        // no need to mix async/await and .then
        React.useEffect(() => {
            axios.get(`https://514c-119-157-87-212.ngrok-free.app/listing/${item.id}/feedback`)
                .then(response => {
                    setResponseData(response.data.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }, [refresh]);
```

Here are the docs for [useState](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) and [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) if you would like to read more about them.

Comment: thanks dude. It did resolve my problem. Sorry I was not able to reply you on time was too busy with other modules functionality. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. If you think it could help others, you can mark my answer as accepted, or if you solved it a different way, feel free to answer yourself and accept that.